# ssl setup in odoo with apache2 with wsgi for single domain but server has multiple domain

Tags: apache, odoo, wsgi

I have configure a apache wsgi setup for odoo with multiple domain and only one domain is setup with ssl on same server but when i try to open with https://domain_name (non ssl site) it is showing ssl site contain but the domain name is same and when i try to open http://domain_name it works perfect and ssl setup site is works fine.

Comment: show your current configuration on the question

Comment: yes please check attachment is an example.